# When compiling Emacs on RHEL8 should I better bind to GTK3 or GTK2?

Tags: x11, gtk3, widget

I am compiling Emacs 27.1 on a RHEL8 Linux box. This RHEL system is a remote system I log in from my Windows machine using MobaXterm (Personal Edition V12.1) on the Windows machine as X server.

On this new-ish  RHEL system GTk2 and GTK3 is installed. On other Unix machines with older OSes I use GTK2 for Emacs. **Is it better to use GTK3** which is available to me on the RHEL8 system?

Comment: I suspect that it is "better" in some sense to use GTK3, but I don't know for sure. What I do know is that I build Emacs (on Fedora 33 and 34) with GTK3 and I have not had any problems. I suspect that  the GTK2 library is made available for older applications that have not made the switch yet. See https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/migrating-2to3.html

Comment: Are those the only two options you're considering?  `--with-x-toolkit=lucid` is very dependable in my experience.

Comment: @phils I’m open to other toolkis, but what packages do I have to yum-install beforehand for lucid?

Comment: For Debianesque distros I think it's just `libxaw7-dev` so see if `yum` has one of those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a follow-up:

I did install Emacs on the RHEL8 system with GTK3 - and under MobaXterm as X server it does not look as "normal" as the GTK2 build from another machine (the scrollbars have strangely thin handles).